# Jacobi $sd(u,m)$ hyperbolic approximation for $m \to 1$

Tags: approximation, hyperbolic-functions, approximation-theory, elliptic-functions

I am following a paper ([Fink 1976](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.14.1028)); the details are a mathematical problem.

We are given a solution (paraphrased from the paper for clarity)

$$y^2 = \alpha m_{1n} sd^2(u,\sqrt{m_n}),$$

where $sd$ is a Jacobi Elliptic Function, and $m_n + m_{1n} = 1$.

In a particular limit, where $m_n \to 1$, we are told that we have an approximation for this equation:

$$y^2 = \alpha m_{1n} \left[\text{cosh}^2(u) \left(1 - \frac{1}{4}m_{1n}\text{sinh}(2u)\right) -1\right].$$

To my eye, it appears that this is a combination of the hyperbolic expansions as given for example in [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions#Approximation_in_terms_of_hyperbolic_functions) or [this page on JE functions from NIST](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.10):

$$\operatorname{sn}\left(z,k\right)=\tanh z-\frac{{k^{\prime}}^{2}}{4}(z-\sinh z%
\cosh z){\operatorname{sech}}^{2}z+O\left({k^{\prime}}^{4}\right),$$
$$\operatorname{dn}\left(z,k\right)=\operatorname{sech}z+\frac{{k^{\prime}}^{2}}
{4}(z+\sinh z\cosh z)\tanh z\operatorname{sech}z+O\left({k^{\prime}}^{4}\right).$$

No such expression is given as an approximation for $sd$.

What I cannot understand is how the factors of $ \pm z$ in the terms can possibly be removed from these expressions. Any advice or guidance would be appreciated - I have tried using other approximations since $m_{1n}$ is small such as $1/(1-x)$ expansions to deal with the denominators etc.

EDIT:
An additional check is given by solving this resulting expression for $m_{1n}$ and the limit that $u$ is large:

$$m_{1n} \approx 4 e^{-2u}[ 1 - \sqrt{1-y^2}].$$

Comment: I think $\,(1 - \frac{1}{4}m_{1n}\text{sinh}(2u) -1)\,$ must be a typo because the $1-1=0$ and vanish.

Comment: Dear Somos - thank you for your keen eye! Yes, there is a small typo here; I have missed a bracket after the sinh, such that the cosh does not multiply the final 1. I have corrected above; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The definition of Jacobi elliptic functions is given in terms of amplitude $\phi$ by the relation \begin{align}u&=\int_0^{\phi}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}}\tag{1}\\
\operatorname {sn} (u, k) &=\sin\phi\tag{2}\\
\operatorname {cn} (u, k) & =\cos\phi\tag{3}\\
\operatorname {dn} (u, k) & =\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2\phi}\tag{4}
\end{align}
The function $\operatorname {sd} $ in your question is defined by $$\operatorname {sd} (u, k) =\frac{\operatorname {sn} (u, k)} {\operatorname {dn} (u, k)} \tag{5}$$ When $k=1$ then we have $$u=\log(\sec\phi+\tan\phi), \sec\phi=\cosh u, \tan\phi=\sinh u\tag{6}$$ And then using $(5)$ we have $$\operatorname {sd}^2 (u, k) =\tan^2\phi=\sinh^2 u$$ However this does not resemble the expression in question.

Perhaps there are some more details which are not available in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think a problem with this approach is that it assumes a fixed value of k=1, rather than taking the limit/expansion as k approaches 1. I have managed to obtain the answer but with some leftover terms, which I can physically try to argue are negligible. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

We are given that
$$\operatorname{sn}\left(z,k\right)=\tanh z-\frac{{k^{\prime}}^{2}}{4}(z-\sinh z%
\cosh z){\operatorname{sech}}^{2}z+O\left({k^{\prime}}^{4}\right), \tag{1}$$ and
$$\operatorname{dn}\left(z,k\right)=\operatorname{sech}z+\frac{{k^{\prime}}^{2}}
{4}(z+\sinh z\cosh z)\tanh z\operatorname{sech}z+O\left({k^{\prime}}^{4}\right). \tag{2}$$
Divide the power series to get
$$ \operatorname{sd}(z,k)=\sinh z-\frac{{k^{\prime}}^{2}}{4}\left(z\cosh z%
+\frac12(-3+\cosh 2z)\sinh z\right)+O\left({k^{\prime}}^{4}\right). \tag{3}$$
Square this power series to get
$$ \operatorname{sd}(z,k)^2 =\sinh^2 z-\frac{{k^{\prime}}^{2}}{4}(z\sinh 2z%
+(-3+\cosh 2z)\sinh^2z)+O\left({k^{\prime}}^{4}\right). \tag{4}$$